# Compiling & Decompiling dll files

Tags: dll

I have a .dll file which I've decompiled with the software called "Reflector7.4.1" to get the source code. After decompiling, to my surprise, I got a folder instead of a single source code file.The folder contained a bunch of other files and subfolders with files.

I have identified the file in which I have to modify the code.But the problem is,after I have modified the only 1 file, how do I compile the whole bunch of folders and subfolders and many other files that I have not edited-into a single .dll file as they were before?

Answer (score 1):

You should not recompile decompiled code, since the compilation process is not completely reversible, even for .NET binaries. There are many missing libraries you might need, mismatches in libraries, etc. I would suggest decompiling and then patching the DLL using a .NET assembly editor of some sort.

[Reflexil](http://reflexil.net) is one you should check out.

You should also understand .NET disassembly and understand how to move back and forth from the decompiled source and the binaries, so you'll know exactly what you want to change.